# Django - updating m2m field value after save

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

The problem is, that after saving a model instance with new m2m_field value, I want to automatically add some more related objects to it.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    m2m_field = models.ManyToManyField("app.RelatedModel")

    @receiver(models.signals.m2m_changed, sender=MyModel.m2m_field.through)
    def m2m_field_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.m2m_field.add(related_object_instance)
```

That obviously results in an infinite loop, because after adding the instance to the m2m_field, the receiver is fired again and so on. Is there a proper way to do it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check first if the related object has been added before or no:

```py
@receiver(models.signals.m2m_changed, sender=MyModel.m2m_field.through)
    def m2m_field_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if related_object_instance not in instance.m2m_field:
            instance.m2m_field.add(related_object_instance)
```

Comment: That's still an infinite loop, because at first it isn't added, and after running .add(), instance.m2m_field still doesn't include the instance and so on

Comment: could put a break after `instance.m2m_field.add(related_object_instance)` and check how to get the record in instance.m2m_field?

Comment: breakpoint after .add() isn't ever going to be called

Comment: hmm I'm not sure I understand. Any line of code written after instance.m2m_field.add() isn't going to be run, since stack overflow is going to occur prior to it